# Android: Not able to get proper data from ArrayList of LinkedHashMap

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap, adapter

I am using ArrayList of LinkedHashMap to pass the data to adapter, but when I am fetching the data inside adapter it is showing the same data again and again. Data which is coming on adapter is the last data of that ArrayList.
I want all the data in adapter.

TransactionalDetailsActivity:

```
package eukti.myafterclass.ui;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import eukti.myafterclass.R;
import eukti.myafterclass.adapter.TransactionalDetailsAdapter;
import eukti.myafterclass.controller.CallRestApi;
import eukti.myafterclass.utils.Constants;

public class TransactionalDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SharedPreferences afterClassPref;
    private String student_uuid;
    private ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
    private TransactionalDetailsAdapter transactionalDetailsAdapter;
    private ListView transactionListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transactional_details);
        afterClassPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        student_uuid = afterClassPref.getString("studentUUID", null);
        transactionListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.transactionListView);
        getMyTransactionalDetails();
    }

    private void getMyTransactionalDetails() {
        TransactionalDetailsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TransactionalDetailsActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.setMessage("please wait, fetching data... ");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        });
        Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
        paramMap.put("student_uuid", student_uuid);
        paramMap.put(Constants.UC_KEY, "transactionaldetails");
        paramMap.put(Constants.MODULE_KEY, "student");
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams(paramMap);
        Log.d("Transactional Details ", "params: " + params);
        CallRestApi.get(Constants.BASE_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("Transactional Details ", " Response :" + response);

                if (response != null) {
                    try {

                        if (response.getBoolean("status")) {
                            JSONArray resultArray = response.optJSONArray("result");
                            if (resultArray != null) {
                                arrayList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
                                LinkedHashMap<String, String> myOrderMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

                                for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject mainJsonObj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Log.d("transaction_date", mainJsonObj.getString("transaction_date"));
                                    myOrderMap.put("transaction_date", mainJsonObj.getString("transaction_date"));
                                    myOrderMap.put("activity", mainJsonObj.getString("module"));
                                    myOrderMap.put("activity_details", mainJsonObj.getString("activity"));
                                    myOrderMap.put("transaction_type", mainJsonObj.getString("transaction_type"));
                                    myOrderMap.put("points", mainJsonObj.getString("count_point"));
                                    arrayList.add(myOrderMap);
                                }
                                transactionalDetailsAdapter = new TransactionalDetailsAdapter(TransactionalDetailsActivity.this, arrayList);
                                transactionListView.setAdapter(transactionalDetailsAdapter);
                                transactionListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                                transactionalDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                transactionListView.invalidateViews();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (progressDialog != null) {
                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TransactionalDetailsAdapter:

```
    package eukti.myafterclass.expandtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import eukti.myafterclass.R;


public class CustomExpandAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<SampleTO> parentRecord;
//    private HashMap<String, List<String>> childRecord;
    private HashMap<String, List<Map<String,String>>> childRecord;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Activity mContext;

/*public CustomExpandAdapter(Activity context, List<SampleTO> parentList, HashMap<String, List<String>> childList) {
        this.parentRecord = parentList;
        this.childRecord = childList;
        mContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }*/


    public CustomExpandAdapter(Activity context, List<SampleTO> parentList, HashMap<String, List<Map<String,String>>> childList) {
        this.parentRecord = parentList;
        this.childRecord = childList;
        mContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
//        return this.childRecord.get(((SampleTO) getGroup(groupPosition)).getTitle()).get(childPosition);
        /*Log.d("Inside getChild","childPosition: "+childPosition);
        Log.d("Inside getChild","groupPosition: "+groupPosition);*/
        return this.childRecord.get(((SampleTO) getGroup(groupPosition)).getSubjectUUID()).get(childPosition).get("topicName");
    }


    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//        Log.d("Inside getChildView","childPosition: "+childPosition+" groupPosition "+groupPosition);
        String childConfig = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        ViewHolder holder;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_child, null);
                holder.childTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTitle);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.childTitle.setText(childConfig);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//        Log.d("Inside getGroupView"," groupPosition "+groupPosition);
        SampleTO parentSampleTo = parentRecord.get(groupPosition);

//        Log.d("Inside getGroupView"," parentSampleTo "+parentSampleTo.getSubjectUUID()+" >>> "+parentSampleTo.getTitle()+" >>> "+parentSampleTo.getCount());

        ViewHolder holder;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.parentTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentTitle);
//                holder.parentIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentIcon);
                holder.count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.parentTitle.setText(parentSampleTo.getTitle());
//            holder.parentIcon.setBackgroundResource(parentSampleTo.getIcon());
            holder.count.setText(parentSampleTo.getCount());

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        private TextView childTitle;
        // Content
        private TextView parentTitle;
//        private ImageView parentIcon;
        private TextView count;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.childRecord.get(((SampleTO) getGroup(groupPosition)).getSubjectUUID()).size();
    }

    @Override
    public SampleTO getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.parentRecord.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.parentRecord.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Several things i observer here: Your getItem() Method returns `null`. You  should use a Viewholder with your listview. Your getItemId() Method also returns 0 every time.

Comment: I am trying to put all these values now.

Comment: @Shivam: try moving LinkedHashMap<String, String> myOrderMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); inside for() loop of TransactionalDetailsActivity.

Comment: @Shivam: did it worked?

Comment: @kevz no its not working. Now my app is crashing because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this implementation

```
package eukti.myafterclass.expandtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class TransactionalDetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<Map<String, String>> mArrayList;
private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public TransactionalDetailsAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, String>> arrayList) {
    mArrayList = arrayList;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView dateTextView;
    TextView activityTextView;
    TextView activityDetailsTextView;
    TextView transactionTypeTextView;
    TextView pointsTextView;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mArrayList.get(position).hashCode();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.transactional_details_items, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        viewHolder.activityTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activity);
        viewHolder.activityDetailsTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activityDetails);
        viewHolder.transactionTypeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        viewHolder.pointsTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.points);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Map<String, String> itemData = mArrayList.get(position);

    viewHolder.dateTextView.setText(itemData.get("transaction_date"));
    viewHolder.activityTextView.setText(itemData.get("activity"));
    viewHolder.activityDetailsTextView.setText(itemData.get("activity_details"));
    viewHolder.transactionTypeTextView.setText(itemData.get("transaction_type"));
    viewHolder.pointsTextView.setText(itemData.get("points"));

    return convertView;
}
```

}

And think about replacing map of strings with class containing all needed data

Activity changes

```
private List<Map<String, String>> arrayList;

arrayList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> myOrderMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Comment: You have just replaced BaseAdapter to BaseExpandableListAdapter?

Comment: No I dont want to use BaseExpandableListAdapter. Is there any other way

Comment: And you have changed ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> to List<Map<String, String>>. Can I keep first one only.

Comment: Yes you can. But the best style of Java programming is to use interfaces instead of exact implementation. If you have Map<String,String> its doesn't matter is it HashMap<String,String>, LinkedHashMap<String,String> or TreeMap <String,String>

Comment: Can you modify Activity's code also, because it is giving me error if I am making it like List<Map<String, String>>

Comment: And some remarks about how to improve code. 1. It's very convenient to use JSON libraries (like GSON or Jackson) to parse JSON data directly to data classes. 2. Consider using RecyclerView instead of ListView, it's modern android programming way)

Answer (score 0):

Your Adapter implementations is incorrect check [this](https://github.com/developer--/DAGS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/geolab/dags/adpaters/ListViewAdapter.java) Adapter code implementation

Comment: if you use this if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.transactional_details_items, null);
            } snipet you should use viewholder patter, also need else block and so on...
your getItem should return your object by its position. see the link I have gave you

Comment: you must modify your getView method also